# How to compare size of string in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSString in Objective-C that I want to find the size of and then compare it to some number; however, I'm not sure what the proper way to do this is?

What I have so far is a property called `display` which is a `UILabel *` and what I'm thinking of doing is the following:

```
NSUInteger size = [self.display.text length];
```

However, now I want to compare this size with a `0`.  But I'm not sure what the proper way to do this?  I've thought of doing the following, but for some reason this doesn't seem right:

```
if(size == 1) { doSomething};
```

Any help?  Thanks

Comment: is your definition of its size equal to its length?

Comment: Yes, I would like size to be equalt to the length of the string

Comment: while we're talking about basic objective-c usage... I would also do self.display.text.length, instead of using square braces. It's a bit neater, and I suspect it might be faster too (not sure about that).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert So does that mean that lenght is a property of a NSString?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is a property or not. You can use the "." syntax or the square braces syntax for anything (as long as it doesn't require method arguments). Dot notation is often cleaner, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the proper way to do it. If you want to check if there is a string whose length is greater than 0 i.e. not just `@""`, compare it with zero like this

```
NSUInteger size = [self.display.text length];
if(size>0) {
    //do something 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `-[NSString length]`. This just returns the number of characters in the string. `NSString` abstracts the encoding of its underlying buffer, but `length` should abtract that from you! This is different from `std::string.size()` or `strlen`, which will return the byte count, independent of encoding.

Thus, you may write `0 == str.length` to determine if the string is empty, or `1 == str.length` to determine if it is one character (encoding-safe).